# Create an infinite URL without MVC?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, hierarchical-data

How can I create an infinite URL from some data hierarchy, using URL routing but without MVC? For instance, an example data hierarchy might be:

- Electronic

  - Television
  - Sound Systems
  - Computer
  - Scaner
  - Mouse

    - Wireless Mouse
  - Keyboard

and the generated URL for the wireless mouse would be:

```
http://www.domain.com/products/electronic/computer/mouse/wireless-mouse/related-product.aspx
```

Comment: You can hook into somewhere and edit the URL before processing. There's a few ways to do this, e.g. as an ISAPI filter in IIS or in your global application object inside ASP.NET. If you do this you'll probably have to turn off IIS's "check page exists" flag on the extension you're using. Or you can probably auto-generate the pages and directories etc. on your server.

Comment: if you are using IIS 7 you can also look for URL Rewrite Module http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 0):

The routing used in MVC isn't actually part of MVC but a separate part of the .net framework. This means that you can use it in the same way you would with MVC, there is just a bit more a set up as there is no default mapping.

A quick google search for asp.net routing with web forms turns up quite a few results, this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc668201.aspx) seems to have all the relevant details - including a section on using routing with web forms.